# Can the partial sum of a monotonic non-increasing convergent (to zero) sequence is in $o(n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is non-increasing sequence that converges to $0$. For convenience let $a_1 \leq 1$. Suppose $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.
Is it possible to show that $\exists \alpha \gneq 0$ s.t. $S_n \in O(n^{1-\alpha})$? If not, can it be shown that $S_n \in o(n)$?

Comment: It's always true if you allow $\alpha = 0$, but not if you restrict to $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: You have $S_n \in o(n)$, but it can be something like $\Theta(n/\log n)$ or so.

Comment: @DanielFischer you got me. Can you please tell me how to prove $S_n \in o(n)$?

Comment: You don't even need monotonicity. If a sequence converges, the sequence of Cesàro means converges to the same limit. Here, $S_n \in o(n)$ precisely means that the Cesàro means converge to $0$.

Comment: See [e.g. here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571297/cesaro-means-convergence).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks man!