# Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence in $(0, 1)$ . Prove that $a_k \to 0$ iff $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \to 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_k  \to 0$ then  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \to 0$ can be established using cauchy theorem on limits, which states that,

if $\lim_{n \to \infty} l_n = l$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k  = l$.

Converse of Cauchy  theorem on limits does not hold in general [a counterexample would be $\{(-1)^n\}$].

So how do you prove that

If $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \to 0$ then $a_k  \to 0$ provided that $(a_k) \in (0, 1)$

Comment: more http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571297/cesaro-means-convergence?rq=1

Comment: No, this is different: it's going in the other direction.

Comment: Hi Spaceman - notice that your counterexample (while otherwise valid) does not obey the restriction "$(a_k)$ [is] a sequence in (0,1)".

Comment: $a_n = \mathbf{1}[n\text{ is a square}]$ has zero Cesaro mean.

Comment: Yeah, @SangchulLee, but the problem there is that that sequence isn't contained in the *open* interval $(0,1)$. (The issue mainly being the many $0$-terms.)

Comment: @Chris Ah, we need a minor modification, then. Thankfully Robert Israel showed a way.

Comment: I'll edit the question..... My counterexample is for Cauchy theorem on limits and not for the proposed problem

Comment: Followup question: If  $(a_k)$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers  such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k  = 0$, must $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_k = 0$?

Comment: Should I ask the above as my own question, or is it OK as a comment?

Comment: Never mind -- it's obvious that the answer to my followup question is "yes".

Comment: @quasi: I'd say it is obvious that the answer to your last followup question is "no". $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = 0$ **does not** imply that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n$ exists.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio -- In my followup question, I did specify that the sequence $(a_k)$ converges.

Comment: All right, but in such a case it is trivial anyway. If $a_n\to c$, then $\frac{A_n}{n}\to c$ too, hence if we know that $\frac{A_n}{n}\to 0$ and $a_n$ is convergent, $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio -- I did say it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

For example, try $a_{2^n} = 1/2$, $a_n = 1/2^n$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, let $A_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n$.

**1.** $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}\text{ infinitesimal}\Rightarrow\{A_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}\text{ infinitesimal}$.
This is kind of trivial: if a sequence is infinitesimal, it is infinitesimal *on average*, too.
For any $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N_\varepsilon$ ensuring $|a_n|\leq\varepsilon$ as soon as $n\geq N_\varepsilon$. 
It follows that if $n=kN_\varepsilon$ with $k>1$ we have
$$|A_n| \leq \left|\sum_{k=1}^{N_\varepsilon}a_n\right|+(k-1)N_\varepsilon \varepsilon $$
so $\frac{A_n}{n}$ is bounded by $2\varepsilon$ in absolute value as soon as $n$ is big enough. $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary and we are done.
We do not need the non-negativity of $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, just its bounded-ness, following from the $\text{infinitesimal}$ assumption.

**2.** $\{A_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}\text{ infinitesimal}\Rightarrow\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}\text{ infinitesimal}$.
This is simply false, even with the assumption $a_n\in (0,1)$. It is enough to consider the sequence given by $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is not a power of $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ if $n$ is a power of $2$. This sequence is infinitesimal *on average* but not infinitesimal *tout court*. This converse of **1.** requires stronger assumptions on the behaviour of $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ or $\{A_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}$. [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy's_inequality) gives a glance at the possible additional assumptions we may require to make **2.** hold. As remarked by quasi in the comments, "*$\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent*" is one of them, but "*$\{A_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}\in\ell^p$ for some $p>1$*" works just as well.

Comment: What is an infinitesimal sequence?

Comment: @zhw.: a sequence converging to $0$.

Comment: I guessed as much, but it is unusual language.

Comment: @zhw. I guess that depends on geography and history. In my courses, it was commonly used, and I think "infinitesimal" is a useful and clear shortcut for "convergent to zero".